# Implementing SSO with .Net 4.0 webforms and Azure AD

Tags: .net, azure, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

We are starting with Azure AD to implement SSO on a website developed with webforms and Office 365, so I was reading about it, and as far as I understand, we need to use some nuggets like these

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect 
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies 
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
```

Now, to install it, we need the 4.5 .NET framework on our project, but it was developed using 4.0 framework.

Does anyone know what's the best approach to connect a webform 4.0 web application to Azure AD? All the information I have found on Microsoft documentation is oriented to MVC and uses libraries like 4.5 OWINs

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you still have problem about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The *Microsoft OWIN aka Katana* require the .Net Framework 4.5 according to here:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin/Microsoft.Owin.csproj

If you want to using the Katana in your project to integrate with Azure AD, you need to upgrade your project to .Net Framework 4.5.

Or you will need to implement the OpenId connect flow yourself in the web form app. You can refer the OpenId connect flow from link below about the detail:

[Authorize access to web applications using OpenID Connect and Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code)